# Python GUI Programming Using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

So I am creating a game, and now I have decided to add a GUI. The GUI code is shown as follows:

```
master = Tk()
master.wm_title("Main Menu")

a = Button.grid(master, text = "DOMINATE!", command = difficulty)
a.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
a.pack()
mainloop()

b = Button.grid(master, text = "Patch Notes", command = changelog)
b.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
b.pack()
mainloop()

c = Button.grid(master, text = "Credits", command = credit)
c.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
c.pack()
mainloop()

d = Button.grid(master, text = "Rules", command = rules)
d.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
d.pack()
mainloop()

e = Button.grid(master, text = "Quit", command = exit)
e.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
e.pack()
mainloop()
```

I have already imported the function * from Tkinter and this is just a snippet of my 1200 lines of code. When I try to run it, I get this error:

TypeError: unbound method grid_configure() must be called with Button instance as first argument (got Tk instance instead)

(Python is kind of a new language for me so sorry for missing anything obvious or stupid. I am also kind of new to programming).

Comment: At a glance, try replacing all the instances of `Button.grid(` with just `Button(`

Comment: As a general rule of thumb. If you find yourself repeating a similar line 3 or more times, use a loop.

Comment: @JoelCornett -- This would be a somewhat clunky loop (have to change `text`, `command`, `row` and `column` at each iteration).  not that it's impossible, but I'm not sure if it would make the code more clear ...

Comment: @mgilson: Maybe you're right. Sorry. Knee-jerk reaction to repetitive code. I was thinking along the lines of using a dict of functions to replace a series of similar if..elifs. In this case You could store the button data in a data structure, and iterate over the data structure to create the buttons.

Comment: @JoelCornett -- Usually I agree with you -- and depending on how the rest of the code is actually structured, you might still be right.  It's just not completely repetitive here.

Comment: `mainloop` is designed to be called only once. I can't imagine how your code runs the way you have it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "unbound method grid_configure() must be called with Button instance..." comes from lines that look like this:

```
a = Button.grid(...)
```

What the above does is try to call the `grid` method on the `Button` class, rather than on an instance of the `Button` class. Generally speaking, any "unbound method" error means exactly that -- you're trying to call a method on a class rather than an instance.

Instead, you must first create an instance of the `Button` class, then call `grid` on the instance. For example:

```
a = Button(...)
a.grid(...)
```

Also, using both `pack` and `grid` for the same widget makes no sense. Use one or the other. If you use `grid` you don't need to call `pack`.

Finally, `mainloop` is designed to be called exactly once after all your widgets have been created.

On a related note, in my experience GUI code is much easier to maintain if you put all your layout code (`grid`, `pack` and `place`) together. Not necessarily all together for the entire app, but at least grouped by the containing window. For example, instead of this:

```
a = Button(...)
a.grid(...)
b = Button(...)
b.grid(...)
...
```

... I recommend doing it like this:

```
a = Button(...)
b = Button(...)
...
a.grid(...)
b.grid(...)
```

This sort of code organization makes it easier to spot layout problems such as having multiple items in the same row or column, etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix this and clearing things up. I will take your  method of GUI programming organization and apply it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
a = Button(master, text = "DOMINATE!", command = difficulty)
a.grid(row=...,column=...)
```

Also, don't do

```
a.grid(...)
a.pack(...)
```

Using `pack` and `grid` on the same widget (or even within the same widget) will likely leave your computer sitting there forever trying to negotiate a reasonable layout between the two geometry managers.  Either use only pack, or only grid.

Finally, you only need the last `mainloop()`.  You should remove all the others -- although if you have 1200 lines of code, I suspect that correcting these things will raise other errors.

Answer (score 1):

The main error comes from the 'master' which is not a Button instance in :

```
a = Button.grid(master, text = "DOMINATE!", command = difficulty)
```

do instead :

```
a = Button(master, text = "DOMINATE!", command = difficulty)
Button.grid(master.a,row=0,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1,sticky='wens')
```

the line for grid placement use the Button superclass grid method for Tkinter Old-style classes. but you don't seem to need that so you could do :

```
a.grid(master.self,row=0,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1,sticky='wens')
```

Doing :

```
a = Button(master, text = "DOMINATE!", command = difficulty).grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=1,sticky='wens')
```

"a" will not be a Button instance callable later, as it will be a grid instance equal to NoneType. 
Split both creation and placement.

Comment: "it will be a grid instance" is incorrect terminology. It won't be a _grid instance_, it will be the value returned by the grid function.